# What would cause memory errors

Tags: linux, memory, dell-poweredge

We had three boxes in the span of 3 days that went down due to memory errors, two of which went down within 2 hours of each other. All the boxes showed errors like:

```
ECC single bit correction warning rate exceeded, ECC single bit correction failure rate exceeded.
```

which is pretty self explanatory. My question is is it random lock that they had issues with in a few days or can it be something environmental causing it? ON reboot one box is hanging on

```
Configuring memory ...Done.
```

The other two boxes came up after a reboot. I want to be scientific about the issue. If there is a bad DIMM should a stress test show the issue or can the issue randomly creep up?

I am running some basic test and so far everything looks clean. Shouldn't a stress test re-produce the issue?

Update: I tested with memtest+ and it came back clean.

Answer (score 1):

If several machines fail at the same time (or report significantly increased error rates) it's either a vast coincidence, bad power, heat, or radiation.

You'll want to check the power, temperatures and locate the errors, swap the DIMMs around a bit and check whether the errors move along with them.